# Add a value to an array in a MongoDB document

Tags: php, mongodb

Let's say we have this document:

```
Array
(
    [created_at] => 1373767280
    [email] => admin@mysite.com
    [emailQueries] => Array
        (
            [21] => 1
        )
    [last_visit] => 1375033640
)
```

To update the `emailQueries` field, I do that:

```
$updateEmailQueries['emailQueries']['22'] = 1;
$collection->update( array('email' => $user['email']), array( '$set' => $updateEmailQueries ) );
```

It updates it, but it always replaces the existing item in the array (ie the [21] => 1 here would become [22] => 1).
My goal is to add values to the array, and make it look for example like:

```
    [emailQueries] => Array
        (
            [21] => 1
            [22] => 1

        )
```

I tried adding a second `'$set'`, but doesn't seem to make it.

Update:

I tried:

```
$updateEmailQueries['emailQueries']['21'] = 1;
$collection->update( array('email' => $user['email']), 
                     array( '$push' => $updateEmailQueries ) );
```

And I get

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`$push` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#add-an-element-to-an-array).

```
$arrayValueToAdd = array ( '22' => 1 );
$collection->update(   array('email' => $user['email']), 
                       array( '$push' => 
                           array( 'emailQueries' => $arrayValueToAdd ) 
                       )
                    );
```

Comment: change `$updateEmailQueries` to `$updateEmailQueries['emailQueries']`, or to the line in my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Using this also returns a fatal error, the same as in my post update.

Comment: Have you tried executing a query like this in the mongo console? Make it work there, then try in PHP.